# JavaScript Can't Find Elements from New HTML Document

Tags: javascript, html

The changing innerHTML of id totalNumber is executing before the html file is changed. How do I fix this?

```
function startPayment() {
  let accounts = document.getElementById('#accountNumber').value;
  let total = document.getElementById('#total').innerHTML;
  if (accounts >= 20) {
    document.location.href = "payment.html";
    document.getElementById('#totalNumber').innerHTML = total;
  } else {
    alert("Minimum Accounts Not Met");
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML of the newly loaded file

```
<div class="paymentForm">
  <h1 class="payment">Payment</h1>
  <h2 class="totalFinal">Total: $ <span id="#totalNumber" class="totalNumber">0</span></h2>
  <input id="#nameOnCard" class="cardInput" placeholder="Name on Card"></input>
  <input id="#cardNumber" class="cardInput" placeholder="Card Number"></input>
  <input id="#cardExpiration" class="cardInput" placeholder="Card Expiration (MM/YY)"></input>
  <input id="#CVN" class="cardInput" placeholder="Card Verification Number"></input>
  <div id="#backBtn" class="backBtn">Back</div>
  <div id="#submitBtn" class="submitBtn">Submit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us the HTML

Comment: just added it ;) @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut

Comment: try removing the # from the ID's

Comment: How is the script loaded into the file? How is the function called? You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: remove all # like from here id="#nameOnCard"

Comment: @Nick, Is your problem solved ? Feel free to accept the best answer to close topic thks

Answer (score 0):

**Main Answer (w/ Update)**

If I understand your problem correctly, you have this function running on a container page like `order.html` which then swaps in a whole different page `payment.html` (because of your `window.location.href` script).

If that's the case, you are trying to pass data from page to page and the JS you're running will definitely disappear before the new page loads. I would recommend updating the URL with a parameter that you pass and then parse with a new script on the page to modify the HTML document.

`window.location.href=payment.html?total=20`

Then when you load `payment.html`, you'll need a JS block in here to then parse the URL for the data generated on the last page.

And for the record, there are definitely other solutions that you can explore as well to save data from one page and access it somewhere else, but that is a simple one to try and see if it helps to solve your problem.

**Side Note**

An issue with the code you supplied is the way you have defined IDs in the HTML. While the selection of IDs with JS is correct if you were using jQuery (i.e., `#totalNumber`), but way IDs using the `getElementById` and defining them in HTML just require the string itself and not the hash mark indicator.

In other words:

```
<!-- Correct -->
$('#totalNumber')
document.getElementById('totalNumber')
<span id="totalNumber">...</span>

<!-- Incorrect -->
document.getElementById('#totalNumber')
<span id="#totalNumber">...</span>
```

The other issue I'm seeing (which may be omitted intentionally) is that your JS code refers to HTML elements not included in the HTML snippet you provided.

If you need any additional clarification, please let me know!

Comment: yes but this still does not solve the problem at hand

Comment: JS is not correct too.  `document.getElementById` doesn't accept hashtag. Don't confuse it with jquery

Comment: @nick As far as load order goes, I'm assuming the JS script is at the bottom of the page correct?

Comment: @GGO you're completely right. thanks for pointing that out. that's what I get for trying to answer a question first thing in the morning. appreciate it!

Comment: @nick I've updated my answer to consider the real problem you were having at hand and I think I understood what was wrong. If I'm still misunderstanding something, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You have `#` in your html attributes (this is not W3C valid) and in js function parameter. You have to remove them like :

```
<div class="paymentForm">
  <h1 class="payment">Payment</h1>
  <h2 class="totalFinal">Total: $ <span id="#totalNumber" class="totalNumber">0</span></h2>
  <input id="nameOnCard" class="cardInput" placeholder="Name on Card"></input>
  <input id="cardNumber" class="cardInput" placeholder="Card Number"><C/input>
  <input id="cardExpiration" class="cardInput" placeholder="Card Expiration (MM/YY)"></input>
  <input id="CVN" class="cardInput" placeholder="Card Verification Number"></input>
  <div id="backBtn" class="backBtn">Back</div>
  <div id="submitBtn" class="submitBtn">Submit</div>
</div>
```

And with this javascript :

```
function startPayment() {
  var accounts = parseInt(document.getElementById('accountNumber').value);
  var total = document.getElementById('total').innerHTML;
  if (accounts >= 20) {
    document.location.href = "payment.html";
    document.getElementById('totalNumber').innerHTML = total;
  } else {
    alert("Minimum Accounts Not Met");
  }
}
```

NB : to compare `accounts` and `20` you have to use `parseInt` function, i added it in my correction

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem in your script add param in url:

```
function startPayment() {
  var accounts = parseInt(document.getElementById('accountNumber').value);
  var total = document.getElementById('total').innerHTML;
  if (accounts >= 20) {
    document.location.href = "payment.html?total=" + total;

  } else {
    alert("Minimum Accounts Not Met");
  }

}
```

And then after loading of new html page on document load do this

```
var url = new URL(document.URL);
var total = url.searchParams.get("total");
document.getElementById('#totalNumber').innerHTML = total;
```

Comment: instead of using 'document.URL' you can use 'window.location.href' if you have any problem.

Comment: I say it again, `getElementById` doesn't accept hashtag in parameter ...

Comment: @GGO you can see the html. What Nick has written in html <span id="#totalNumber" class="totalNumber">0</span>  so document.getElementById('#totalNumber') will work fine. I have tried also it works fine no hashtag issue.

Comment: That's right is works, but it's not a good practice, it's not w3c valid and nobody shouldn't encourage anybody to code like this

Comment: Yes, I know that and we should not use 'hashtag' in id of any html element. I am not encouraging anybody to code like this. We can suggest it to people, But in this question solution is required that I have given hashtag is not an issue here.